# Is this a correct correlation coefficient keras metrics?

Tags: deep-learning

I want to ask about if the code below can calculate the correlation coefficient correctly as I want to use it as a 
keras metrics?

```
def correlation_coefficient(y_true, y_pred):
    pearson_r, update_op = tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_pearson_correlation(y_pred, y_true, name='pearson_r')
    metric_vars = [i for i in tf.local_variables() if 'pearson_r'  in i.name.split('/')]

    for v in metric_vars:
        tf.add_to_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, v)

    with tf.control_dependencies([update_op]):
        pearson_r = tf.identity(pearson_r)
        return 1-pearson_r**2
```